# Is this sentence grammatically correct in the past tense?

Tags: past

I'm currently doing my German speaking assessment and I just want to make sure this sentence is right.

> Ich bin nach der Schule blieben mein Kunstbuch vollenden und meine
>   Lehrerin hilft mir.

I'm trying to say:

> I stayed after school to finish my art book and my teacher helped me.

Is it correct? It's just the last sentence I need to go over and I'll be finished.

Comment: Welcome to German.stackexchange! Please visite the tour to get to know more about this site: http://german.stackexchange.com/tour This site is not for individual spell/grammar checking, so this question will be closed likely. To avoid this, could you please specify why you think your sentence might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. Actually, there are 3 mistakes in the sentence. The correct translation reads:

> Ich bin nach der Schule **geblieben**, **um** mein Kunstbuch **zu** vollenden und meine Lehrerhin **half** mir.

- **geblieben** is the participle of "bleiben" which is demanded by the Perfekt tense "ich bin geblieben"
- **um zu vollenden** is the correct Infinitiv in the Infinitivsatz (infinitive clause) and the correct translation of "to help me" - see (for instance) [easy deutsch](https://easy-deutsch.de/satzbau/infinitiv-mit-zu/) for further explanations
- **half** (english: "helped") is the correct Präteritum of "helfen". Another possibility is to use Perfekt here as well, i.e. "und meine Lehrerin **hat mir geholfen**". Actually using Perfekt would be better style than Präteritum here.

Comment: Wo kommt die Lehrerin her - im Englischen ist es ein teacher?

Comment: Aus der Frage von KatieBell. Englisch "teacher" kann sowohl femininum als auch maskulinum sein.

Comment: Und Lehrer ist die deutsche, generische Form. Lehrerin kann nicht männlich sein. "Female teacher" wäre "Lehrerin". Analog ist ein "male teacher" mit "männlicher Lehrer" zu übersetzen, denn nur "Lehrer" lässt das Geschlecht offen.

Comment: Englisch *teacher* ist halt wirklich völlig offen. *My teacher is very nice and she is very cool, too* wäre ein ganz normaler englischer Satz. Deswegen kann es Situationen geben, in denen auch ein unspezifiziertes *teacher* mit "Lehrerin" zu übersetzen ist - wenn man nämlich aus dem Kontext weiß, dass es sich um eine Frau handelt. Eben das ist hier der Fall.

Comment: Das weiß man eben nicht, weil es nur in der dt. Übersetzung auftaucht. Da das Original das Geschlecht offen lässt sollte es die Übersetzung auch tun. Wenn das Original im Kontext offenbart hat, dass es sich um eine Frau handelt, wäre es die Aufgabe einer Übersetzung dies auch im Kontext zu offenbaren. Die Betonung des Geschlechts ist ein Ausdruck der dt. Version, die sich im Original nicht findet - es kann also allenfalls sein, dass es sachlich richtig ist, dass es eine Frau ist. Stünde in der dt. Übersetzung "alter Lehrer" oder "rothaariger Lehrer" wäre das genauso zu kritisieren.

Comment: Ich halte diese Diskussion hier nicht mehr für produktiv. Es ist in meinen Augen offensichtlich, dass die realweltliche Situation, die im Ausgangspost einmal auf englisch, einmal auf deutsch beschrieben wird, eine weibliche Lehrerin beinhaltet. Natürlich steht es nicht so im englischen Satz, aber ich glaube, das ist allen klar. Die Entscheidung, hier "Lehrerin" zu schreiben ist die pragmatisch richtige, weil die Antwort so auf das reagiert, worum es der Fragestellerin geht.

Comment: @userunknown Übrigens ist die Übersetzung des englischen Satzes "My teacher is nice." als "Meine Lehrerin ist nett." ebenso falsch/richtig wie "Mein Lehrer ist nett." Im englischen Satz liegt keine Geschlechtsspezifizierung vor; die Aussage, "Lehrer" (im Singular!) wäre die generische, ebenso unspezifizierte Version, ist falsch. Das wird etwa deutlich, wenn man den Satz "Mein Lehrer ist nett. Sie hilft mir immer bei den Hausaufgaben" betrachtet. Kaum jemand käme hier wohl auf die Idee, "Lehrer" als die generisch maskuline Version der weiblichen Person ("sie") im zweiten Satz zu verstehen.

Comment: Würdest Du behaupten, dass, wenn man weiß, dass die Person weiblich ist, der Begriff Lehrerin zu benutzen ist? Ist das politisch motiviert? Würdest Du auch behaupten, dass man, wenn man weiß, dass es ein männlicher Lehrer ist, man "männlicher Lehrer" schreiben muss, um das Geschlecht hervorzuheben? Woran erkennst Du, dass es der Fragestellerin darum geht?

Comment: @userunknown @*Würdest Du behaupten, dass, wenn man weiß, dass die Person weiblich ist, der Begriff Lehrerin zu benutzen ist?* Ja, natürlich. Das ist nicht politisch motiviert, sondern schlicht die sprachliche Realität. Wie klingt denn "Mein Mathelehrer Frau Meier" für dich? Normal?

Comment: (Hier kreuzten sich die letzten 2 Kommentare, der vorletzte war noch nicht da, als ich begann). Du führst Annahmen ein über Folgesätze, die sich nicht aus der Frage ergeben. Wäre, hätte, Fahrradkette. Teacher hat im Englischen kein Geschlecht. Im Deutschen hat das Wort männliches Geschlecht. Über das Geschlecht der Person ist damit nichts gesagt. "Mein Mathelehrer, Frau Meier" ist vollkommen korrekt.Bei der Gestaltung eines Textes, in dem das Geschlecht eine Rolle spielt würde man aber nicht unbedingt Satz für Satz übersetzen - es käme dann aber auf den Kontext an, den wir hier nicht haben.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55237/discussion-between-jonathan-scholbach-and-user-unknown).

Answer (score 0):

As a native German speaker, I would directly translate it to:

"Ich bin nach dem Unterricht in der Schule geblieben um mein Kunstbuch zu vollenden. Dabei hat mir meine Lehrerin geholfen."

If you want to say "[…]staying after school[…]" you have to connect it to the end of the event, which, is in that case, the end of all your classes on a school day. It translates to:

"[…] nach dem Unterricht."

Furthermore, you have to correct "blieben" to "geblieben", because "bleiben" uses "Ich bin" instead of "Sie (plural)". Lastly, using "um" does connect the reason for staying after all your classes with the task, which is, finishing your art book.

Comment: Why don't you suggest "und mein Lehrer half mir"? Wo kommt die Lehrerin her? Wieso einen neuen Satz beginnen?

Comment: Likely because "Lehrerin" is what the OP suggested.